# By what mechanism can I short a commodity without the use of futures of that commodity?

Tags: united-states, options, shorting-securities, futures, commodities

I live in the US and I work for a company that is heavily related to a particular commodity X. As such, when I began working for them, I signed a document stating that I would not purchase stock/ETFs/Mutual funds/etc... that were composed of or reliant on any futures for this commodity X. This is unfortunate, as I believe the price of said commodity is going to drop in the medium term, and I would like to short it. I obviously can't short my own company's stock. What mechanisms do I have at my disposal to short this commodity given my restrictions? Can I instead short the stock price of a company that isn't mine and is heavily involved in the generation of commodity X, for example? This appears to be the closest way to do so legally, but I want to make sure I am not missing some alternative mechanism?
Edit: Forgot to note this, but the decision/desire to short this commodity is **based entirely on publicly available information** and not dependent on some secret insider information. My understanding of how the commodity works in general comes from experience working at this company, but I don't have insider knowledge of some upcoming event or movement of the commodity that isn't public.

Comment: To close a short position, you have to buy the security, which violates your agreement with the company.  Since your company is "heavily involved" in that commodity, if you have material non-public information about the company and use that as the basis for trading you may violating SEC insider trading laws too.

Comment: @NorgateData see the edit, its based on public information. I also understand that there's no way around buying a security. But my restriction is specifically on futures. A competitor's stock doesn't contain that commodity's futures and I have no specific restriction on purchasing their stock. I am just looking to ensure that I'm not missing a more direct methodology for shorting the commodity.

Comment: To be clear, do you *have* insider information about this commodity? If you have the information, then it doesn't matter whether you're actually basing your decision on that information or not; the legal system can't see inside your head.

Comment: @TannerSwett thank you for clarifying that. No I do not. I am sure that other people in the company may have knowledge of the volumetric movement of the commodity or internal projections of its price, but that is information I do not have access to.

Comment: A falling commodity price is *beneficial* to some companies, causing profits to rise, and thus increasing the share price.  Will the falling commodity price cause your company to *lose* profits?

Comment: Let's suppose X is mined by company Y. Your theory here is that Y has large fixed expenses, so if the price of X falls, the value of company Y will fall even more; Y becomes a less valuable company because it is harder for them to make a profit. And your conclusion is that shorting Y is a proxy for shorting X directly. Is that correct? And do you have evidence from past movements of the price of X that producer Y's price moves in lockstep?

Comment: @EricLippert that is my general conclusion, yes. I have only done some rudimentary analysis to support this assertion... by checking the price of commodity against the price of the stock of company Y and noting that the direction and magnitude of the movements line up (ever so slightly delayed, though)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to short a security is to create a Synthetic Short using its options, if they exist.

This  strategy utilizes two option positions.  A short call is sold and the proceeds are used to buy a long put, both  with the same strike and expiration. This combination has a similar risk and reward to shorting the underlying with the difference being that the Synthetic Short has a time limitation (expiration).

There are several possible issues with this strategy:

- If you have specific contractual language forbidding the shorting of this commodity and/or shorting your company's stock, it's likely that you may have similar prohibitions for synthetics
- If the underlying moves up or down significantly, the short call may be assigned early if it's an American style option, resulting in a short position in the underlying

Therefore, your only alternative might be to short a similar stock that has no such prohibitions.

Comment: I can do some google searches to understand what a Synthetic short is, but can you explain to me what the difference is between this and simply going long on a put option? If my intention is to make money from a falling stock price, why would I choice synthetic shorts over long puts?

Comment: @KingG0at - In your question, you asked about shorting the "stock price of a company that isn't mine".  A synthetic short tends to cost nothing, often put on for a small credit and it duplicates a short position in the underlying.  It  is useful when the underlying security cannot be borrowed for shorting.  Long puts and short the underlying have different costs and different risk/reward characteristics as well as different margin  so while  they're directionally similar to the downside, they're not the same.

Comment: Note that since most (if not all) commodity options are actually options _on futures_ it may still violate the restrictions that have been placed on you.